# ReactJS unrecognised token import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to learn to use ReactJS but I am have hit an issue and I can't seem to find the right thing to fix it.

I've installed npm and run `npm --install react` and `npm --install react-dom` in the root of my project. The project is HTML/Javascript posting to a PHP backend, I am not using NodeJS which seems to come up a lot in what I've been looking at, but from my understanding, Node isn't a requirement.

I have the following js file

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";
$(document).ready(function(){

    postToMiddleware(null, "account-manager.php", "testReact", function(result){
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));

        ReactDOM.render("<Names />", document.getElementById("names"));
    })
});

class Names extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Hello here is my react component</p>
        );
    };
}
```

My HTML page includes the javascript file above but I then get an error in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The line that it is complaining about is the very first line:

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

If it makes any difference - I assume not, I'm on Windows running under Wamp, although when it goes live it will be on a Linux box running Apache.

**UPDATE**
I've since found an alternative to the import and changed the two import lines as follows:

> var ReactDOM = require("/node_modules/react-dom/"); var React =
>   require("/node_modules/react");

But now in Chrome I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Which is complaining about the line `<p>Hello here is my react component</p>`in the render return

Comment: You can't use react code like that in the browser without transpliling it. Stick with @tomasz suggestion to use a boilerplate app with all settings predefined

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - you get this error because you need to transpile JSX syntax. Transpiler will covert it to react objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [babel](https://babeljs.io) to transpile features like `import` statements and other es6 features not yet available in modern browsers. If you are new to react consider using [create-react-app-boilerplate](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which handles all of that and more for you.

Comment: Thanks I saw about babel, is that a requirement for reactjs, I have also changed the import to require which seems to give me a different error, is that because babel is required. It looks like the boilerplate app uses node which I don't want to use, is that the case?

Comment: It isn't, but you may need it in order to import and export modules with that syntax.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html Check out react docs on how to use react without es6 features. If you are using npm then you are already using Node.

Comment: It looks like the boilerplat uses node. I just want to set up some PHP pages with HTML/Javascript using react to process and display data from a backend. React seems to not like doing what I want to do without node and node is js backend so can't process PHP/HTML pages so I think I might be looking for an alternative to react

Comment: @Boardy you only need Node if you are going to do server-side rendering. You can still just server bundled assets as static content, like you would normally do with html, js and css.

Comment: Hmm I'll keep looking, everything I've seen seems to rely on node and use a ton of different plugins

Comment: @Boardy like I said, you only need node localy for development purposes. When you are finished just run `npm run build` (with create-react-app) and you will get folder with all the assets (html, css, js, static resources) bundled to the `build` directory. You can then just serve these like you would normally serve html. And yes there is more to that, but for what you are trying to achieve you can do just that.

Comment: Hmm looking a bit more, I don't think this is suitable for what I want as I need PHP as well, Having a quick look around I think AngularJS might be more suitablee for what I want

Comment: Thanks for the help I've accepted the answer as what you've said is correct, but I don't think I'll be using React after all, going to use a library at `https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/jquery-lazy-template` does exactly what I was hoping React would do but without any compilations of transpiling